# Voice Instruction in HERE Maps is not working

Tags: android-studio, here-api

I want to implement the Voice Instructions by HERE Maps on Android, I used the Sample Code "LiveSightGuidanceActivity" and I added the Code related to the Voice instruction from [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-voice-instructions.html) 
But the Voice is not working! and I got the error

> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

here's a piece of code from the sample

```
  // Setup navigation manager
        m_navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();
        m_navigationManager.setMap(m_map);
        m_navigationManager.setMapUpdateMode(MapUpdateMode.NONE); // No need to update map as LiveSight already does so
        attachNavigationListeners();

        stopNavigationManager();



        // Disable navigation sounds
        m_audioFlags = m_navigationManager.getEnabledAudioEvents();
        m_navigationManager.setEnabledAudioEvents(EnumSet.allOf((NavigationManager.AudioEvent.class))); // it was nonOf

        // Disable traffic avoidance mode as we use pedestrian guidance
        m_navigationManager.setTrafficAvoidanceMode(TrafficAvoidanceMode.DISABLE);


        // Start navigation in Simulation Mode
        NavigationManager.Error error = m_navigationManager.simulate(m_liveSightMapRoute.getRoute(), SIMULATION_SPEED);

        if (error != NavigationManager.Error.NONE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to start navigation. Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            m_navigationManager.setMap(null);
            return;
        }



        m_navigationManager.setNaturalGuidanceMode(EnumSet.of(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.JUNCTION));
        setupVoice();
```

And here's the full setupVoice() method

```
 private void setupVoice() {

        // declare the listeners
// add application specific logic in each of the callbacks.

      instructListener = new NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onNewInstructionEvent() {
                // Interpret and present the Maneuver object as it contains
                // turn by turn navigation instructions for the user.
                m_navigationManager.getNextManeuver();
            }
        };

        positionListener = new NavigationManager.PositionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPositionUpdated(GeoPosition loc) {
                // the position we get in this callback can be used
                // to reposition the map and change orientation.
                loc.getCoordinate();
                loc.getHeading();
                loc.getSpeed();

                // also remaining time and distance can be
                // fetched from navigation manager
                m_navigationManager.getTimeToArrival(true,
                        Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.DISABLED);
                m_navigationManager.getDestinationDistance();
            }
        };

        // start listening to navigation events
        m_navigationManager.addNewInstructionEventListener(
                new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener>(instructListener));

        // start listening to position events
        m_navigationManager.addPositionListener(
                new WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(positionListener));

        // Retrieve the VoiceCatalog and download the latest updates
        VoiceCatalog voiceCatalog = VoiceCatalog.getInstance();

        if (!voiceCatalog.isLocalCatalogAvailable()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Voice catalog is not available in local storage.");
            //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog is not available in local storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            voiceCatalog.downloadCatalog(new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
                    if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
                        // catalog download successful
                        Log.d(TAG, "Download voice catalog successfully.");

                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog download successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Download voice catalog failed.");

                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog download error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // Get the list of voice packages from the voice catalog list
                    List<VoicePackage> voicePackages =
                            VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getCatalogList();
                    if (voicePackages.size() == 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Voice catalog size is 0.");

                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog size is 0.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    long id = -1;
                    // select
                    for (VoicePackage voicePackage : voicePackages) {
                        if (voicePackage.getMarcCode().compareToIgnoreCase("eng") == 0) {
                            if (voicePackage.isTts()) // TODO: need to figure out why always return false
                            {
                                id = voicePackage.getId();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!VoiceCatalog.getInstance().isLocalVoiceSkin(id)) {
                        final long finalId = id;
                        VoiceCatalog.getInstance().downloadVoice(id, new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
                                if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
                                    //voice skin download successful
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Download voice skin successfully.");

                                    //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice skin download successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    // set the voice skin for use by navigation manager
                                    if (VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(finalId) != null) {
                                        m_navigationManager.setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(finalId));
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Get local voice skin error.");

                                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Navi manager set voice skin error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Download voice skin failed.");
                                    //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice skin download error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // set the voice skin for use by navigation manager
                        if (VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(id) != null) {
                            m_navigationManager.setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(id));
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Get local voice skin error.");
                            //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Navi manager set voice skin error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: @marco Could you please help ?, I so need the voice instruction urgently

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183443/here-sdk-navigation-sound-is-not-playing  In the end of the answer, I also linked a full working example you can use.

Comment: @marco I worked thank you so much, I'm just wondering is it possible to make it "Start Navigation" immediately without "waiting for GPS fix" ? because it takes so much time to Start Navigation button to appear

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the MobileSDK by HERE is using the system TTS engine that's setup on your Android. So please make sure your Android has a TTS engine installed and set (often this is Google TTS, some OEMs don't set a engine like my Sony Z5, or some have another one, like LG with sfplus for example).

Once Android has the TTS capabilities, the flow should look like following on HERE SDK side:

1. Check the already installed TTS Skins of the HERE SDK:

   ```
   List localInstalledSkins = VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkins();
   ```

   If the voice you want is already downloaded locally, jump directly to 4. otherwise continue with next step.
2. Get the voice catalog from the HERE Servers:

   ```
   VoiceCatalog.getInstance().downloadCatalog(VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener)
   ```

   In the listener callback you can query the list of available language for download via:

   ```
   List packages = VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getCatalogList();
   ```
3. Download a VoiceSkin you wanna play:

   ```
   VoiceCatalog.getInstance().downloadVoice(skin_id_from_catalog_you_want_to_use, VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener)
   ```

   Make sure the listener returns with success before you continue with next steps.
4. Set the downloaded voice skin for navigation:

   ```
   NavigationManager.getInstance().setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(skin_id_you_want_to_use))
   ```
5. Kick off guidance

You can get full project source from the HERE servers: http://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/TtsAndNavigation.zip